# Android How to change String with Edittext and reuse in same activity

Tags: android, xml, string, credit-card-track-data

I have a serious problem, I have a card swiper app that passes all of card data threw a xml (the way the xml is structured in my code was writted by the sdk provider). I need to make it possible to do a manual entry using 2 EditText (1 for Card number and 1 for ExpDate) and then pass that data to the same Activity (OR A NEW Activity) to be used in the xml that processes the order. Can this be done? How can this be done? Below is my Code - and edits or corrections will be very helpful ... Thank you in advance.

```
String tranXmlFmt =  
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><TStream>" 
      + "<Transaction>" 
      + "<IpAddress>66.173.160.125</IpAddress>" 
      + "<MerchantID>002649</MerchantID> " 
      + "<OperatorID>50</OperatorID>" 
      + "<TranType>Credit</TranType>" 
      + "<CardType>VISA</CardType> " 
      + "<TranCode>Sale</TranCode> " 
      + "<OperatorID>55</OperatorID> "
      + "<InvoiceNo>100001</InvoiceNo>" 
      + " <RefNo>100001</RefNo> " 
      + "<PartialAuth>Allow</PartialAuth>"
      + "<Account>" 
      + "<AcctNo>4104891389583005</AcctNo>"  
      + "</Account> " 
      + "<ExpDate>0214</ExpDate>"
      + "<Amount><Purchase>13.00</Purchase></Amount>" 
      + "<UserTraceData>GBTE130116</UserTraceData>"
      + "</Transaction> " 
      + "</TStream>";
String initXml = "" 
    + "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" 
    + "<TStream><Admin>" 
    + "    <MerchantID>002649</MerchantID>"
           + "    <TerminalID>002</TerminalID><TranCode>SecureDeviceInit</TranCode>"
           + "    <PadType>None</PadType>" + "    <TranType>Setup</TranType>"
           + "    <SecureDevice>UniMagSecureMagDsi</SecureDevice>" 
           + "    <ComPort>1</ComPort>" 
           + "  </Admin>"
           + "</TStream>";
    '
```

Help

```
Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextScreen);
    //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
            //Starting a new Intent



        }
    });
      Button btnInit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInit);
    btnInit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /**
         * initialize epay client 
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            libReady = true;
            ca = new ClientActivity(getApplication(), readerType);
            Log.d("MAINACTIVITY", "reader type: " + readerType.toString());
            initReturn = ca.initialize(initXml);
            Log.d("MAINACTIVITY", "init return: " + initXml);
            libReady = true;
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editXml);
            et.setText(initReturn);
            Log.d("MAINACTIVITY", "Library Loaded");

        }
    });

    Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Close_button);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LineDisplay ld = new LineDisplay();
            ld.open(DeviceCommon.DEVICE_MODE_COMMON, null);

            ld.clear();             
            ld.setBacklight(LineDisplay.LCD_BACKLIGHT_OFF);

            ld.close();         
            finish();
        }
    });
```

I just need to add 2 Edittext and change the AcctNo and ExpDate STRING to be used in this same activity. please any help will be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data from edittext and pass it to your secondactivtiy using intents.

```
     String s1,s2
     EditText ed1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editext); 
     EditText ed2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editext2);

         on Button click

     s1 = ed1.getText().toString(); 
     s2 = ed2.getText().toString();
     ed1.setText("");  
     ed2.setText("");
```

In same activity. Can keep other tags as above.

```
     String xml ="<AcctNo>"+s1+"</AcctNo>"  
          + "<ExpDate>"+s2+"</ExpDate>"; 

             OR

    Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondactivity");
    i.putExtra("key1",s1);   
    i.putExtra("key2",s2);  
    startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity you can retrieve the values.

```
    String value1,value2;   
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
    value1 = extras.getString("key1"); 
    value2 = extras.getString("key2"); 
    }
```

Can keep other tags as above.

```
    String xml ="<AcctNo>"+value1+"</AcctNo>"  
          + "<ExpDate>"+value2+"</ExpDate>";
```

EDIT :

acitivity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:ems="10" />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
   android:text="TextView" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="TextView" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText ed1,ed2;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
Button b;
String s1;
String s2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            s1= ed1.getText().toString();
            s2= ed2.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("................"+s1);
            System.out.println("................"+s2);
            tv1.setText(s1);
            tv2.setText(s2);
            String xml ="<AcctNo>"+s1+"</AcctNo>"  
                      + "<ExpDate>"+s2+"</ExpDate>";
            System.out.println("................"+xml);
            tv3.setText(xml);
            ed1.setText("");
            ed2.setText("");
        }

    });

}

}
```

As you can see it works. See the snap shot. I have 3 text views, 2 editext's and a button.
After user types in editext's i click the button and i set the values to textview. 
As you can see the values reflects in string xml which is the result set in textview3.

[image]

Comment: But I need my Second Activity to be the same as the First ... is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean by same?. Get text from editext, append values to the required tags. Keep the other tags as same.

Comment: I have to add the new EditText values to the "String tranXmlFmt" or else I get error.

Comment: on button click retrieve values and clear editext. So next time user types you get new values.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that now. Thank you in advance, I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: You need to make changes to string xml and pass string xml to another activity? You can do the same as above passing value using intents.

Comment: My code is to long, but what you see above is the exact code, and I have to edit the AccountNumber (AcctNo) and the ExpDate so the strings are changed to the new data. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you have to post your code. see the edit and the snapshot. Aftet clicking button the values are set and edittext cleared. You can send xml to another activity.

Comment: check the edit. If you can't post any code (relevant code). I don't think i can help you any further. But you can modify my code accordingly.

Comment: I gave it a try and the Textview does change however the String doesn't, nor is it reusable.

Comment: I gave it a second try and the Code works Perfectly! @Sirisak rebuild your project according to the code defined here!